# I am using this code for pop up a textfield with Cancel & Submit options, but keyboard is also showing.I don't want to show the keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I am using this code for pop up a `TextField` with Cancel & Submit options, but the keyboard is also showing. I don't want to show the keyboard with a popup.

```
@IBAction func can(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let alertController : UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "Confirm Order ?", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
alertController.addTextField {

    (textField : UITextField!) -> Void in

    textField.placeholder = "Expected Time"

    textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.myTargetFunction(sender:)), for: .touchDown)


    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "CANCEL", style: UIAlertAction.Style.destructive) {
        (UIAlertAction) in
    }

    let CANAction = UIAlertAction(title: "SUBMIT", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default) {
        (UIAlertAction) in

        ValidateClass.showToast(self.view, title: "Alert", Msg: "Please select the expected time", alertType: 1)

    }
    alertController.addAction(okAction)
    alertController.addAction(CANAction)

    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
}
```

Comment: How is the user going to type into the text field if the keyboard isn't shown?

Comment: on the text field click a function is called who will show the pickerview and the selected data will be the placeholder of that textfield.

Comment: A textfield has an inputView property, set that property to be the pickerview.

Answer (score 0):

As a default behaviour, the `Keyboard or UIPickerView` (if inputView set to UIPickerView) will show if we add `UITextField` on `UIAlertController`

So as per your requirement, you need to do:

First set UITextField's `inputview` property to `UIPickerView` and hide keyboard/UIPickerView.

```
textField.inputView = self.pickerView
textField.resignFirstResponder()
```

then, declare variable to check is user clicked on a text field or not. here I used `isTextFieldClicked` as boolean.

```
var isTextFieldClicked = false
```

Update `myTargetFunction` to set value and show `UIPickerView`

```
self.isTextFieldClicked = true
sender.becomeFirstResponder()
```

In `UITextField` delegate method, check and return true if `isTextFieldClicked` value is true.

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
            if isTextFieldClicked == false {
                textField.resignFirstResponder()
                return false
            }
            return true
        }
```

This will solve your problem,sure...

Cheers!

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. At least add a brief explanation of what was wrong and how this solves the issue.

Comment: @rmaddy thanks for the feedback, updated answer with explanation.